# transform ordered dictionaries to list of dictionaries iteratively

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

EDIT: I realized I made a mistake in my data structure and updated it.

I have an ordered dict with some values as list and some as list of lists:

```
odict = OrderedDict([('A', [33]),
                     ('B',
                         [[{'AA': 'DOG', 'BB': '2'},
                           {'AA': 'CAT', 'BB': '1'}]]),
                     ('C',
                         [['01','012']])
                     ])
```

I am currently manually adding the keys and values in this function:

```
def odict_to_listdict(odict, key1: str, key2: str, key3: str) -> list:
    return [{key1: v, key2: v2, key3: v3} for v1, v2, v3 in \
         zip(odict[key1], odict[key2], odict[key3])]
odict_to_listdict(odict,'key1','key2','key3')
```

that gives me the expected output of a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'A': 33,
  'B': [{'AA': 'DOG', 'BB': '2'}, {'AA': 'CAT', 'BB': '1'}],
  'C': ['01', '012']}]
```

I plan to add more keys, values, how do I iterate through the ordered dict without explicitly typing the keys while maintaining the expected output, for example:

```
[{'A': 33,
  'B': [{'AA': 'DOG', 'BB': '2'}, {'AA': 'CAT', 'BB': '1'}],
  'C': ['01', '012']}],
  'D': 42,
  'E': [{'A': 1}]
}]
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in second dictionary. That should be `{'key1': '2', 'key2': 'Orange', 'key3': 'bla'}`

Answer (score 1):

First off, from Python 3.7+ you can use normal `dict` since it maintains the insertion order.

You can re-write your function like:

```py
def odict_to_listdict(odict):
    keys = list(odict)
    return [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in zip(*odict.values())]
```

Test:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

odict = OrderedDict()
odict['key1'] = ['1', '2']
odict['key2'] = ['Apple', 'Orange']
odict['key3'] = ['bla', 'bla']

def odict_to_listdict(odict):
    keys = list(odict)
    return [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in zip(*odict.values())]

print(odict_to_listdict(odict))
```

output:

```
[{'key1': '1', 'key2': 'Apple', 'key3': 'bla'}, {'key1': '2', 'key2': 'Orange', 'key3': 'bla'}]
```

**Explanation :** 
You can get the keys from the dictionary itself, no need to pass it to the function.

the iteration part of the `odict` is basically iterating through the `odict` dictionary in parallel.

For the expression part of list comp, you need to zip the `keys` and the values which get returned from the iteration part.

Comment: I made a mistake, your solution worked for when all my values are lists. I realize some are list of lists and updated the question